# W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/

Tags: debian, upgrade

I am using Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). After run sudo apt update I get this error:

> W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Has anyone had a similar problem and have any advice?

Comment: Are you sure the software from an Ubuntu-targeting ppa is compatible with your Debian? Those are two different distros!

Answer (score 2):

The certificate is wrong. It have `CN=ppa.launchpadcontent.net` and you access `ppa.launchpad.net`. Edit your config file to point to new URL

Comment: That. Also confused how they are using an Ubuntu trusty repo with a Debian bullseye system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I am not a Debian person :)